# Render/Import component only after a dynamic import finishes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lazy-loading

I have a component A that's being dynamically imported with nextjs dynamic. I want Component B to only render after component A is loaded or at least they load together.

here's the current code snippet:

```
const A = dynamic(() => import('../A').then((mod) => mod.A),{ ssr: false });
const B = dynamic(() => import('../B').then((mod) => mod.B),{ ssr: false });
```

This will not give the desired behavior because the import happens async. So I thought of importing B inside the dynamic call of A like so:

```
const { A, B } = dynamic(
  function () {
    const A = import('../A').then((mod) => mod.A);
    const B = import('../B').then((mod) => mod.B);

    return { A, B };
  },
  { ssr: false },
);
```

I thought this way I could get both components, but I got an error saying:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.